# Ошибка Ajax запроса, в ответе specialchars \u0022\u003E\n [drupal 8]

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Ответ в формате json приходит со specialchars

Часть ответа для примера

```
{
 "command":"insert","method":"append",
 "selector":"body","data":"\u003Cscript 
  src=\u0022\/core\/modules\/editor\/js\/editor.dialog.js?
  v=8.5.1\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E\n\u003Cscript 
  src=\u0022\/core\/misc\/dialog\/dialog.ajax.js?
  v=8.5.1\u0022\u003E\u003C\/script\u003E\n","settings":null
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня это происходило по причине преждевременного вывода. У меня этот вывод происходил в одном из файле класса формы, но для примера можно и в

**`index.php`**
 сверху вначале добавить любой тег

```
<code></code>
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
 *
 * All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
 * See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt files in the "core" directory.
 */

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
try {
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Sorry, error';
}
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Работать сайт у вас будет нормально но во время ajax запросов будет происходить екранирование ответа. Случилось такое просто как опечатка, но заняло несколько часов поиска, совсем не в том месте

Разумееться для решения нужно проверить наличие такого преждевременного вывода и убрать его.